# Single Page Application with Cookie Based External Identity Provider Login and Token Delegation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

How do you create a seamless login flow for a single page application using third party open id connect provider (such as Google or Microsoft) that then generates a new jwt token from an existing one returned by the external provider without refreshing the page?

For example, I want a user to be able to log into Google, then be brought back to my site where I validate the token server side using IdentityServer4, then extract certain claims and generate a new JWT (my own logic).

Is there an existing IdentityServer4 endpoint that validates JWT tokens from Open Id Providers at the redirect and then what's the best approach to injecting my own token creation flow afterwards? The end result is a ideally a cookie containing my new JWT token that will now be sent on every http request my SPA makes.

My best guess is to use the oidc js client and set up a user manager for Google, for example:

```
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
    authority: "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    client_id: "---",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:60720/account/callback",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile email",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:60720/spa",
});

/*...*/
mgr.signinRedirect();
```

However, on the redirect, I need Google to send a cookie to my controller, which will then use IdentityServer to validate the token, extract some claims like the user id, and then generate a new token for my API. This assumes I'm using IdentityServer to host my own identity provider. How do I use IdentityServer4 to accomplish this last part?

This is simple to do with an MVC pattern because the token is generated on the post back after the redirect callback is invoked. In a SPA, there should be minimal redirection, ideally none where a popup is displayed to allow the user to login and then the SPA takes over. I've been unable to figure out how to redirect from an external identity provider to my IdentityServer4 auth server or MVC server and generate a new token with minimal disruption of the de-facto configuration.

Google recommends that the server must validate the token  (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validate-access-token). One possible solution is to generate my new token in the redirect callback after its validated. However, isn't IdentityServer4 supposed to validate the token, or do I have to do this myself on the server? What part does IdentityServer4 play here in the token validation. I don't want to hand code this step myself.

Comment: Did you eventually solve this ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own grant type with an Identity Server endpoint just to exchange a third party authentication cookie into an internal JSON-bearer based token.